# Is there jQuery plugin for displaying tooltips with content of some other page?

Tags: jquery

Are there any jquery tooltips that could display a content of a provided url? I need it urgently and I've searched and searched and to no avail. I have a page that displays contact information of a certain person (provided in query string) and some other page that displays a list of users. i would like to display this small contact information in tooltip on clicking on a specified user. But I cannot find any tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple tip is one jQuery pluggin.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/

You can load the content via an ajax request.

```
// Create your tooltips
$('JQUERY SELECTOR').simpletip();

// Access the API of a previously initatied simpletip
var api = $('JQUERY SELECTOR').eq(0).simpletip();

// Perform an ajax call and get the contact details from that page.
api.load('myajaxserverpage.php?userid=5');
```

Assuming myajaxserverpage.php will read the querystring value (5) and send an HTML markup for the users contact information.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at qTip, from the same developer as Simpletip.

You'll see from the [FAQ for qTIP](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/support/#faq) that Simpletip is no longer active.

[qTip offers AJAX requests also](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/tutorials/#dynamic)